# If/else proper indentation inside while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I started learning programming with Python about a few weeks now 
and I am having some trouble.
The following code is a tiny program that checks whether there's an even number in a list, if it finds the first even number, it breaks out of the loop:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5]
position = 0

while position < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[position]
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('Found even number', number)
        break
    position += 1

    else:  # break not called
    print('No even number found')
```

That prints the error:

```
File "test.py", line 11
    else:  # break not called
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That's an indentation issue, if I remove the tab before "else" and so align it with 'while' the program runs really well:

```
while position < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[position]
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('Found even number', number)
        break
    position += 1

else:
    print('No even number found')

# Prints: No even number found
```

My question is, why does 'else' needs to be aligned with 'while' instead of being aligned with 'if' inside the loop?

That's all I want to know guys!
Thanx in advance!

Comment: `position += 1` is not indented correctly.

Comment: @AndrewL. Wouldn't it actually be the else statment needs to be indented?

Comment: @bjskistad Didn't read the question all the way through, not sure if OP wants to have `position += 1` outside the if/else. And yes, indent the print call in else.

Comment: Yeah guys, it's the else statement that needs indentation, just found that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the indent you are using a while:else block. The else is being attached to while which means it will run if your while condition is false.

```
while True:
    ##some looping code
else:
    ##code to run when while is false
```

When you indent that line of code you attach the else to if making an if:else block. In this case else is executed when if is false.

```
if True:
    ##code to run if true
else
    ##code to run if false
```

Blocks of code in python follow the same indentation. Because "else" is part of the "while" block, it has to be at the same tab position for it to work, and looking at your code, I'd say the while:else block is what you intended. :)

Comment: Booleans are capitalized in Python :)

Comment: So they are. I'll edit for that. Thanks.

Comment: The `else:` block in a `while: ... else:` block runs if `break` is never executed in the while loop, which is different than your description.

Comment: Thanks, your explantation made me get the hang of it!

Comment: Yeah, the book I'm reading didn't explain that though.

Comment: Now I know, thanks Andrew Hewitt!

Comment: Glad to help. But take note of @cco 's comment, which is also important.

Comment: Yeah, I'm even writing it down!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 5]
position = 0

while position < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[position]
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('Found even number', number)
        break
    else:  # break not called
        print('No even number found')
    position += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem. There are two types of `else` statements in this case. If you align the `else` statement with `while`, the `else` statement is executed when the condition of the `while` loop becomes false.

In your code, the else statement gets executed when `position < len(numbers)` is not true.

Also, the syntax problem is occurring just because you have a line of code between the `if` and `else` statements, which is `position += 1`

If you want to use an `else` statement for your `if` statement (not for the `while` statement as I suggested at the beginning), you should move this line of code in between of `if` and `else`.

Try this:

```
while position < len(numbers):
    number = numbers[position]
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('Found even number', number)
        break
    else:
        print('No even number found')
    position += 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That also did the trick, thanks man!

Comment: Sure! @CodeAddicted